# Расчитать текущую неделю по одной дате календаря

Tags: c#

выбирая дату на календаре, необходимо показать текущую неделю. (*условно пользователь может выбрать среду => показываем с понедельника по субботу*)

мне удалось расчитать понедельник (*формулу нашла пока искала решение*), а вот как найти субботу, чтоб получить текущую неделю (*рабочую*)

```
DateTime test = someValue;
var test2 = someValue2;
//как видно вар лучше смотрится....чтоб визуально дистангировать переменные
```

```
public void SomeMethode()
{
..............................
var currentMonday = DateValue?.AddDays(-(((int)DateValue?.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7)); //✅
var currentSaturd = DateValue?.AddDays(+(((int)DateValue?.DayOfWeek - 6) % 7)); //❌
...................
//я подумала просто поменяю наоборот...
}
```

`DateValue = это дата выбранная пользователем на календаре.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое лучше привязывать к культуре, ибо у разных стран есть свои особенности.

Что-то вроде этого:

```
var dateValue = DateTime.Today; // Текущая дата без времени
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture; // Текущая культура
var weekOffset = culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek - dateValue.DayOfWeek; // Разница между началом недели, и текущим днем.
var startOfWeek = dateValue.AddDays(weekOffset); // Получаем дату начала недели указанной даты
```

Имея это уже можем делать что хотим, например, получить все даты текущей недели:

```
var weekDays = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(i => startOfWeek.AddDays(i)); // На 26 мая (Россия) выдаст с 22 по 28 включительно.
```

Comment: Вы предлагаете то есть неделю тут, если я из списка то есть `linq` вызову, то `between` делать ? //потому что я отходила от логики две даты, а тут даже проще. как я могу к списку применить это не подскажете ? (я то брала меньше той то и больше той то)//`someList.Where(date => date.SomeDateModel.Date >= debut && date.SomeDateModel.Date <= fin).Distinct().ToList();` //а как я могу `weekDays` использовать ?

Comment: есть лист и в нем промежуток дат=`SomeDateValueMyModel` (ну скажем 90 дней) и из этих 90 дней показать эту неделю `weekDays`

Comment: @Dev18 Немного не понял вопроса. Надо для каждого дня в списке получить неделю? То есть, на выходе должен быть список из 90 недель? Если да, то весь код, что я скинул, вынесите в отдельный метод, который будет принимать `dateValue` и культуру (которой задайте значение по умолчанию), ну а дальше просто `var result = mySuperDaysList.Select(x=>MySuperMethod(x));`, где `x` - это каждая дата из списка формата `DateTime`.

Comment: есть лист уже, из этого листа я беру только ТЕ данные которые равны промежутку `weekDays`

Comment: @Dev18 Тогда, что-то вроде [этого](https://dotnetfiddle.net/giWz6I), если правильно понял задачу.

Comment: `var result = currentDates.Where(x => x >= firstDate && x <= lastDate);` а как то можно это условие только `weekDays`  расчитать не применяя две даты больше меньше

Comment: @Dev18 "Между" подразумевает, что есть старт и конец, некие статичные значения, которые я и вытаскиваю. Сказать "Вот список, дай даты, которые в пределах этого листа", думаю такое невозможно, либо будет основано на том-же прицепе, что я показал. Для сокращения, вы можете `.First()` и `.Last()` внедрить в `LINQ` условие, будет одной строкой, но это максимум, что можно тут сделать (наверно).

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentMonday = DateValue?.AddDays(-(((int)DateValue?.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7));
var currentSaturd = currentMonday?.AddDays(5);
```

вот еще может кому пригодится [такое интересное решение](https://markb.uk/csharp-datetime-get-first-last-day-of-week-or-month.html), //там и другие расчеты дат

```
public static partial class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime FirstDayOfWeek(this DateTime dt)
    {
        var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        var diff = dt.DayOfWeek - culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

        if (diff < 0)
        {
            diff += 7;
        }

        return dt.AddDays(-diff).Date;
    }

    public static DateTime LastDayOfWeek(this DateTime dt) =>
        dt.FirstDayOfWeek().AddDays(6);
    public static DateTime LastSaturdayOfWeek(this DateTime dt) =>
            dt.FirstDayOfWeek().AddDays(5);
    public static DateTime FirstDayOfMonth(this DateTime dt) =>
            new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);

    public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth(this DateTime dt) =>
        dt.FirstDayOfMonth().AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

    public static DateTime FirstDayOfNextMonth(this DateTime dt) =>
        dt.FirstDayOfMonth().AddMonths(1);
}
```

Comment: `currentSaturd = currentMonday.AddDays(6)`?